# How do I register multiple users in Firebase Authentication for Android at the same time?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented adding a single user through android app but cannot register multiple users at the same time. 
Is there some java or android code which will allow me to register a large number of users at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase client SDKs (for Android, iOS and Web) are meant to be used in end-user applications. They only allow you to register a single user at once, and that user is immediately signed in.

To register multiple users at once, consider using:

- the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), for which the Authentication functionality is only available in Node.js at the moment.
- the [auth:import command of the Firebase command line tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth-import).

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but would it be possible to utilise the Admin SDK using Cloud functions (Use case: Firebase authenticated user is logged in to end user app (web) and wants to bulk create other user accounts with email+password 'provider', edu app - admin adding staff accounts). Any help or pointers on this greatly appreciated.