# How to keep the existing firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() after creating a new account in firebase android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working with firebase authentication in android.I have created an account using `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndpassword()`.

On success I am creating another account with the same method and signing out the new user. Now the previous user is also being signed out.

I want to keep the first user always logged in. How to avoid the first user from signing out? Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: I believe Firebase only allows a single signed in user per device. Why would two users use the app at the same time?

Comment: like gmail app I want multiple logins in my app.

Comment: As said here, you can't have multiple users logged in at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897547/how-do-i-register-multiple-users-in-firebase-authentication-for-android-at-the-s

Comment: As  Rosário and Ugurcan say, this is indeed currently not possible. If you think this is a common requirement, I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst two users cannot be logged in at the same time, you could have a user who is logged in with a single username and password but then in your app logic, allow them to create and use multiple sub accounts stored under the same login token.

e.g: 1 Account with 2 (or more) sub accounts.